# Need single python regex for the following:

Tags: python, regex

**pattern contains**

- any words and not and like

  examples - 'adsjfjkdsa not like', 'wordsmsj not like'
- any words and like

  examples - 'dakladkl like', 'adsjkjk like'

The regex should be **single regex not multiple** match the follwing patterns:

'jkasjkdsk like'

'anyword not like'

'dsklksd like'

The regex should not match the following words:
'sdkjjksjk notlike'
'sdkjdjsklike'
'jkadjkjkad'

I know that it is possible to check these pattern with two regex patterns.
I want to know if **it is possible in one regex**.

Regex to match first pattern - **r'[a-z]*[\s]like'**

second pattern - **r'[a-z]*[\s]not[\s]like'**

Comment: I suggest you go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to avoid negetive votings next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as simple as this regex : `\w+(?: not | )like`

you can use :

- `\s` instead of  (space).
- `[a-zA-Z]` instead of `\w`

note : `(?: )` is a non-capturing group. reference : 1) [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) 2) [regex doc](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html)

Comment: Thanks.I think \w matches[a-zA-Z0-9_]

Comment: Yeah, sure it does.! Just a small tip: Don't take the negative votes personally. They are because it was an easy question which you can figure out by looking at some docs about regex. But I feel, No question is small.. And keep looking at the up-votes (+5) you get, as it is far too much important than down(-2 only). Welcome.!

Comment: Yeah. I don't mind votes anyway its just an increment of some variable in someone's code ;)